# Dynamic reactive form controls

Tags: javascript, angular, dynamic, angular-reactive-forms, formarray

Requirement  :
There will be two calendar inputs. If user selects the range from May 2020 to May 21. I should create 3 set of 12 dynamic reactive form controls. It should also have required field validations.
PS : Am quite new to this dynamic controls. And I see in some forums to use for formarray. Please help me with some headers. will go ahead with that. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use Angular FormBuilder with FormGroup to create your dynamic form. Inside the FormGroup you can create your 12 fields with different set of FormControl. In the FormControl object you can add the validators of your choice as well.

Comment: Thanks, Dont we need Formarrays? I thought of below approach. And the form-array will have multiple formcontrols dynamically
 <form-group> 
     <form-array>

 </form-array>
     <form-array> </form-array>
     <form-array> </form-array>

</form-grp>

Comment: Yes Lokesh your approach is correct. The formbuilder will help you in creating dynamic form elements